# Parse X509 Certificates in dart and extract Common name

Tags: dart, blockchain, x509certificate, pem

Hi I have a public key which is like

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

xya.....

21esafd......

-----END CERTIFICATE-----

I am trying to extract the common name from the certificate. I could do it online through many pem parsers. Is there a way to achieve this in dart or should i build java-native bridge to achieve this? Also Please note that I am trying to implement a flow which enforces blockchain.

I have tried PemDecode/Encoder. All it does is base64 encode the certificate.

Comment: I believe the PEM lib does it correctly, but you need to actually parse the decoded certificate from its bytes... PEM is not a certificate itself... how to parse the certificate though, I don't know :( but I guess you're looking for a X509 certificate parser (which I couldn't find, but there must be one as Dart:io has a type for that).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, to fetch data from a certificate.

I added this functionality to my utils package.

Github : https://github.com/Ephenodrom/Dart-Basic-Utils

Install :

```
dependencies:
  basic_utils: ^2.2.2
```

Example :

```dart
String x509Pem = "";
X509CertificateData data = X509Utils.x509CertificateFromPem(x509Pem);
String commonName = data.subject["2.5.4.3"];
print(commonName);
```

Check out the other methods of the X509Utils :

```dart
AsymmetricKeyPair generateKeyPair({int keySize = 2048});
String formatKeyString(String key, String begin, String end,{int chunkSize = 64, String lineDelimiter = "\n"});
String generateRsaCsrPem(Map<String, String> attributes,RSAPrivateKey privateKey, RSAPublicKey publicKey);
String encodeASN1ObjectToPem(ASN1Object asn1Object, String begin, String end);
String encodeRSAPublicKeyToPem(RSAPublicKey publicKey);
String encodeRSAPrivateKeyToPem(RSAPrivateKey rsaPrivateKey);
RSAPrivateKey privateKeyFromPem(String pem);
RSAPublicKey publicKeyFromPem(String pem);
Uint8List getBytesFromPEMString(String pem);
RSAPrivateKey privateKeyFromDERBytes(Uint8List bytes);
RSAPrivateKey privateKeyFromASN1Sequence(ASN1Sequence asnSequence);
Uint8List rsaPublicKeyModulusToBytes(RSAPublicKey publicKey);
Uint8List rsaPublicKeyExponentToBytes(RSAPublicKey publicKey);
Uint8List rsaPrivateKeyToBytes(RSAPrivateKey privateKey);
ASN1Object encodeDN(Map<String, String> dn);
X509CertificateData x509CertificateFromPem(String pem);
Future<X509CertificateData> fetchCertificate(Uri uri);
```